# Pyinstaller "Failed to execute script deldogs"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь создать exe файл из питоновского py, использую pyinstaller. Скрипт работает корректно в расширении .py. Процесс компиляции в exe тоже прошёл успешно. Однако при попытке запустить exe файл возникает Fatal Error: Failed to execute script deldogs. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал переустановить pyinstaller, не помогло. Использую Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.1.1 (64 bit)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какую команду сборки использовали

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо созданный exe файл из папки dist перенести в папку со скриптом(который преобразовывался в exe)

Comment: как именно это ошибку: *"Fatal Error: Failed to execute script deldogs"* исправляет?